# How to compute the number of char, line by line

Tags: ruby

I need a Ruby program that, given a file as parameter, returns a hash or array that gives the number of characters for each line.

How can I do this elegantly in Ruby ?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Stack Overflow expects you to show the code you've written that is having problems, and we will help you fix it. Asking us to write your code for you isn't within the scope. Can you show us what you've tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File.open('file_name').map(&:length)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
File.open('file_name').inject([]) do |counts, line|
  counts << line.size
end
```

Take a note that it will also count new line characters.
For file with content

```
aa
aaaa
a
```

the result will be

```
[3, 5, 1]
```

If you don't want to count them, check this method [String#chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp)

Comment: I like this. The array returned can be indexed by the line number to get the count of characters in that line.